# Is there any way to use KeyCloak authentication without using its UI?

Tags: authentication, kotlin, keycloak, rbac, ktor

So, I'm build an API System. I want to use KeyCloak for authentication as well as user management because it has a nice access control. I'm integrating it with Ktor and I want my user to use their own UI. Or at least, I want to make the UI.

I've read about Theme Customization but that's not what I want. I also come to know that the KeyCloak UI is tightly integrated within their code. I was just hoping to know if at least when one of the client app is a mobile app, would I be able to use for example android UI for the whole login flow?

If it's not possible which I think it's unlikely to be possible, is there any other library or framework for access control, prefereably one that work with Ktor?

Comment: Would like to know how you solved your problem? I'm facing a similar one at the moment.

Comment: @ystark I have come to know that some flows don't require UI.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use Keycloak UI nor create your own custom themes, you can leverage the [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2/grants/password.html#resource-owner-password-credentials-grant) flow.

For this create a new or use an existing `confidential` client. Make sure to toggle the `Direct Access Grants Enabled` switch to ON.

After this obtain a token from your client (web page, CLI, mobile). Here I'm using `curl` and `jq` for simplicity:

```
KCHOST=https://yourkeycloak.com
REALM=your-realm
CLIENT_ID=your-confidential-client
CLIENT_SECRET=xxxxxxx-yyyyyyyy-zzzzzzzzz

ACCESS_TOKEN=`curl \
  -d "client_id=$CLIENT_ID" -d "client_secret=$CLIENT_SECRET" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials" \
  "$KCHOST/auth/realms/$REALM/protocol/openid-connect/token"  | jq -r '.access_token'`
```

> P.S. For debugging I have created a CLI tool called [brauzie](https://github.com/maslick/brauzie) that
>   can help you fetch and analyse your JWT tokens (scopes, roles, etc.). It could
>   be used for both public and confidential clients. You could as well
>   use Postman and https://jwt.io

HTH :)

Comment: isn't this `Client Credentials Grant` flow rather than `Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant` flow in which case `grant_type` has to be `password` but in your case it is `client_credentials` . Also, in this the request that you mentioned there is no information about which user do we want to login as. see specification here https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.3

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Keycloak Admin Client as described [here](https://armin-ganic.medium.com/register-a-user-using-keycloak-admin-client-with-kotlin-and-ktor-1aca89ad2761).

Comment: The Admin Client allows administrative actions to be carried out - this is not what the OP wanted. It is possible to create or delete a user using this API, but it is not possible to authenticate the user AFAICT.

Comment: ERROR 404: page not found